# Filterable with multi-select list

Tags: android, android-filterable

I would like to have a multiselect spinner with a search option for it. I have already implemented a spinner with a search option. I would like some help with multiselect.

Here is my code:

**Adapter class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using ViewModels;

namespace Adapters
{
    public class FilterableAdapter : ArrayAdapter, IFilterable
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Filter filter;
        Activity context;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> AllItems;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> MatchItems;

        public FilterableAdapter(Activity context, int txtViewResourceId, List<FilterableListViewModel> items) : base(context, txtViewResourceId, items)
        {
            inflater = context.LayoutInflater;
            filter = new SuggestionsFilter(this);
            AllItems = items;
            MatchItems = items;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return MatchItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public FilterableListViewModel GetMatchedItem(int position)
        {
            return MatchItems[position];
        }


        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Drawable.filterList_view, null);

            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_itemContent).Text = MatchItems[position].displayName;
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MatchItems[position].subItem))
            //{
            //    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_subItemContent).Text = MatchItems[position].subItem;
            //}
            //else
            //{

            //    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.list_subItemContent).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            //}
            return view;
        }

        public override Filter Filter
        {
            get
            {
                return filter;
            }
        }

        public void ResetSearch()
        {
            MatchItems = AllItems;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class SuggestionsFilter : Filter
        {
            readonly FilterableAdapter _adapter;

            public SuggestionsFilter(FilterableAdapter adapter) : base()
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            protected override Filter.FilterResults PerformFiltering(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(constraint.ToString()))
                {
                    var searchFor = constraint.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("searchFor:" + searchFor);
                    var matchList = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    //var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.title.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? 1 == 1 : i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()));

                    var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.item.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) || (i.subItem != null && i.subItem.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower())));//   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) : null);


                    foreach (var match in matches)
                    {
                        matchList.Add(match);
                    }

                    _adapter.MatchItems = matchList;
                    Console.WriteLine("resultCount:" + matchList.Count);

                    List<FilterableListViewModel> matchObjects = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        matchObjects.Add(matchList[i]);
                    }

                    results.Count = matchList.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    _adapter.ResetSearch();
                }
                return results;
            }

            protected override void PublishResults(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
            {
                _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterableListViewModel.cs:**

```
public class FilterableListViewModel
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string item { get; set; }
   public string subItem { get; set; }
   public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

**filterList_view.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ListView_style">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/list_itemContent"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:text="sample"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="18sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/_4sdp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
   [Activity(Label = "SuburbListActivity")]
    public class SuburbListActivity : Activity
    {
        private FilterableAdapter _adapter;
        private ListView _list;
        private EditText _filterText;
        private ISuburbs suburbInfo;
        Android.App.ProgressDialog progress;
        public ILog Log { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.filter_list);
            ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayOptions(ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom, ActionBarDisplayOptions.ShowCustom);
            // ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Android.Graphics.Color.Black));

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_actionbar_centerTitle, null);

            ActionBar.LayoutParams p = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                   GravityFlags.Center);

            var title = ((TextView)v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.title));
            title.Text = "Select Suburb";

            ActionBar.SetCustomView(v, p);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


            progress= new Android.App.ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.SetProgressStyle(Android.App.ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            progress.SetMessage(WaitMessage);
            progress.SetCancelable(false);

            progress.Show();
            InitializeComponant();
            InitializeEvents();
            BindData();

        }

        private void InitializeComponant()
        {
            suburbInfo = Dependencies.Container.Get<ISuburbs>();
            Log = Dependencies.Container.Get<ILog>();

            _list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.filterList);
            _filterText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.search);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// initialize evnts
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeEvents()
        {
            _list.ItemClick += List_ItemClick;
        }

        private void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var listItem = _adapter.GetMatchedItem(e.Position);
            //var serviceRoleId = listItem.id;
            //var hasPIC = listItem.subItem;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegisterActivity));
            myIntent.PutExtra("suburbId", listItem.id);
            myIntent.PutExtra("suburbName", listItem.item);
            myIntent.PutExtra("postcode", listItem.subItem);
            SetResult(Result.Ok, myIntent);
            Finish();
        }

        private async Task BindData()
        {

            //var serviceRoleList = await serviceInfo.GetAllAsync();
            RegistrationFacade regFacade = new RegistrationFacade(Log, null, null, suburbInfo);
            List<FilterableListViewModel> states = await regFacade.GetSuburbs();

            //List<FilterableListViewModel> testmodel = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
            //testmodel.Add(new FilterableListViewModel { subItem = "abc, goa, panjim", id = "1", item = "abc" });
            //testmodel.Add(new FilterableListViewModel { subItem = "qwe, maha, vasco", id = "1", item = "qwe" });
            //testmodel.Add(new FilterableListViewModel { subItem = "rty, karna, panjim", id = "1", item = "rty" });
            //testmodel.Add(new FilterableListViewModel { subItem = "uio, assa, marg", id = "1", item = "ttt" });
            _adapter = new FilterableAdapter(this, Resource.Drawable.filterList_view, states);
            _list.Adapter = _adapter;

            _filterText.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var searchTerm = _filterText.Text;
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
                {
                    _adapter.ResetSearch();
                }
                else
                {
                    _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(searchTerm);
                }
            };

            progress.Hide();

        }
    }
```

Any help on how I can modify my code to get multiselect list?

This is what I have already:

[image]

Here is my adapter after `Umair's` suggestion:

```
  public class FilterableMultiselectAdapter : ArrayAdapter, IFilterable
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Filter filter;
        Activity context;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> AllItems;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> MatchItems;

        public FilterableMultiselectAdapter(Activity context, int txtViewResourceId, List<FilterableListViewModel> items) : base(context, txtViewResourceId, items)
        {
            inflater = context.LayoutInflater;
            filter = new SuggestionsFilter(this);
            AllItems = items;
            MatchItems = items;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return MatchItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public FilterableListViewModel GetMatchedItem(int position)
        {
            return MatchItems[position];
        }


        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Drawable.filterMultiselectList_view, null);

            view.FindViewById<CheckedTextView>(Resource.Id.chkTV).Text = MatchItems[position].displayName;
            return view;
        }

        public override Filter Filter
        {
            get
            {
                return filter;
            }
        }

        public void ResetSearch()
        {
            MatchItems = AllItems;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class SuggestionsFilter : Filter
        {
            readonly FilterableMultiselectAdapter _adapter;

            public SuggestionsFilter(FilterableMultiselectAdapter adapter) : base()
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            protected override Filter.FilterResults PerformFiltering(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(constraint.ToString()))
                {
                    var searchFor = constraint.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("searchFor:" + searchFor);
                    var matchList = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    //var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.title.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? 1 == 1 : i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()));

                    var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.item.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) || (i.subItem != null && i.subItem.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower())));//   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) : null);


                    foreach (var match in matches)
                    {
                        matchList.Add(match);
                    }

                    _adapter.MatchItems = matchList;
                    Console.WriteLine("resultCount:" + matchList.Count);

                    List<FilterableListViewModel> matchObjects = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        matchObjects.Add(matchList[i]);
                    }

                    results.Count = matchList.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    _adapter.ResetSearch();
                }
                return results;
            }

            protected override void PublishResults(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
            {
                _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly you mean multiSelect list ? do you want to select multiple items in list ? if yes then us can also you checkedTextView instead of a simple textview and work on it accordingly.

Comment: Yes I want to select multiple items in the list and I also need a search option for that list.

Comment: looking at the image you attached it seems you have implemented search option but you are unable to select multiple items.

Comment: check my answer below it will give you the idea how you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CheckedTextView` for selecting multiple items from the spinner dropdown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chkTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/action_settings"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and then in your adapter class's `getView` method do something like this:

```
viewHolder.chkTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.chkTV.isChecked()) {
                viewHolder.chkTV.setChecked(false);
                if (mModel != null) {
                    addItemIntoUnCheckedList(mModel.getId());
                }

            } else {
                viewHolder.chkTV.setChecked(true);
                if (mModel != null) {
                    addItemIntoCheckedList(mModel.getId());
                }
            }
        }
    });


 private void addItemIntoCheckedList(int id) {


    Model phyFac = new Model();
    phyFac.Id = ID;
    // do your model work here for the checkedItem

    if (UnCheckedByUser != null && UnCheckedByUser.size() > 0) {


        for (int i = 0; i < UnCheckedByUser.size(); i++) {
            if (UnCheckedByUser.get(i).getId() == phyFac.getId()) {
                UnCheckedByUser.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    checkedListOfFacilities.add(phyFac);

}

private void addItemIntoUnCheckedList(int Id) {

    Model unCheckedPhyFac = new Model();
    unCheckedPhyFac.Id = ID;
    unCheckedPhyFac.Id = Id;

    if (checkedList != null && checkedList.size() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedList.get(i).getId() == unCheckedPhyFac.getId()) {
                checkedList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    UnCheckedByUser.add(unCheckedPhyFac);
}
```

Now at the end you will get both the unchecked and checked lists using this approach and you can do whatever you want to do with those lists.

Comment: That does not help, the list is not showing up. I tried to only change replace the textview with CheckedTextView and it does not show

Comment: @Arti are you passing this checkedTextView layout as an item layout ?

Comment: Yes. could it because of filterable?

Comment: it shouldn't be doing it because of filterable. but can you check if it's working without filters ?

Comment: What is mModel ?

Comment: @Arti that is your model .. in your case it will be FilterableListViewModel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162729/discussion-between-arti-and-umair).

Comment: how can I get selected items in my activity?

Comment: @Arti well when you get selected items list, the best way to send data back to activity from adapter is to use interfaces. Implement that interface in your activity and you are good to go :)

Comment: Could you please explain me with any example as I am not sure how to go about it

Comment: @Arti yes I can give you the example but it will be in android/java. If you are ok with it :) ?